# Anime series about a teen girl, a guy with glasses and a swordsman who become friends and fight to save the world

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime series I'm looking for might have been made in 2015 or 2014, and I watched it in 2020.

In episode one, a young teen girl is doing rhythmic gymnastics and trying to fight, but her grandma or grandpa tells her that girls can't fight, and she gets mad. Later, she meets two kids her age; one wears glasses, and the other is a swordsman. They become friends and fight to save the world.

In another episode, they were in a river, and the girl gets dragged underwater by a mermaid man because he likes her, but she just wants to to return to the surface. Her two friends try to rescue her but fail. The mermaid man lets them go in the end.

The girl has black hair. The sword guy has brown hair. The glasses guy has black hair.